# Use Google Script to download a file to Google Drive

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a script that downloads a .csv file from a link to my Google Drive, and then access the file's data.  Once I know how to download and get access to the file in Drive, I can complete my script.  I think I can access the file using the class DriveApp, but I still don't know how to get the file into my Google Drive without doing it manually.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the urlFectch method...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little snippet that will help.

```
function saveFile() {
  var url = "http://www.ferc.gov/docs-filing/eqr/soft-tools/sample-csv/contract.txt";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```